# How to use double callback in mocha and supertest

Tags: node.js, callback, mocha.js

I have a test case as

```
it("Searching with valid rollnumber", function(done) {
    DbService.find_random_rollnumber(function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        request.get('/provider')
        .query({id:result.rollnumber})
        .set('Authorization', "Bearer "+token_value)
        .end(function(err, response) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(response.body);
            done();
        })
    });
})
```

where in DbService.js there is a function called find_random_rollnumber written as

```
find_random_rollnumber : function(callback) {
    connection.provider.findOne({}, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        return callback(err, result);
    });
},
```

this is not working and throws an error as

```
Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you expect the test to pass? Do you expect it to fail with a different error? What about your `console.log`? Does it show what you expect? Does it show something else? If the latter, what's the difference between what you expect and what you do get? Did you use other `console.log` statements while trying to debug? What did they show?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do not see any falls in your code, it should work.

For the start I suggest you to increase the amount of time of waiting to 20 seconds to see if the timeout is the problem.

```
describe('', () => {
   it('', done => {
      //do your test
   }).timeout(20000)
})
```

If still is the problem then I guess the problem is somewhere in the event loop that you are not calling a callback...

Comment: The problem is with the result.rollnumber.. when i try to console it, it shows as undefined whereas if i try to console the entire result proper data is shown...

Comment: could you post in comments the console.log of the result ?

Comment: It works fine..problems lies in the collection model creation